# Labeling contour lines in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-10.1, cartography, dem, elevation, contour

Can anybody give me advice on how to label contours as shown in Figure 2 below? I would like to be able to put the label "on" the line, which is easy enough. But I'd also like for the contour line to have a break in between the label, as shown in Fig. 2. Without the break it is very hard to read the label, unless I use a mask with white background as in Fig 1. Maybe there is some sort of "invisible" masking option that creates the break?? I'm using ArcMap 10.1 on Windows 7 (64 bit)

Figure 1
[image]

Figure 2
[image]

Comment: which license level of ArcGIS you have?

Answer (score 5):

**Labeling using the Contour Placement style**

Required:
ArcMap

Clean (good) Data

Maplex Labeling Enabled.
 (see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_the_Labeling_toolbar/00s800000014000000/)

> The Maplex Label Engine groups the segments of contour features, if
>   the symbology and label match and the features are connected, and
>   treats them as single, long features

[image]

Official Documentation on Contour Label Placement

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s800000064000000

Comment: Under properties, label position, choose "Contour Placement". I don not see this option. I am missing something.

Comment: (+1) Maplex is a great tool for labeling contour lines. But as far as I know it can not solve the halo/mask problem. After you have created the labels with Maplex you can convert the labels to annotation and create masks to block the contour features but not the other underlying symbology. To create the mask you need Feature Outline Masks tool which is available with ArcInfo license only. [Here is a detailed instruction how to mask your labels](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/11/28/variable-depth-masking-contour-label-example/).

Comment: Interesting that this is flagged as a duplicate and yet this is the best answer by far!